# How to filter/ add CSS class to an HTML table based on a user's input to HTML form using Java script of JQUERY

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, forms

I am very new to java script/ JQUERY and would appreciate some help.

Basically I have a table with maybe 50-100 entries.

I'm trying to build a website where a user inputs their data into a form and I want the website to hide the table results that doesnt meet their requirements specified on the form OR to add a CSS style class like a green or red border to signal yes or no.

Similar to this website
https://www.prospectivedoctor.com/medical-school-chance-predictor-2/

I'm really struggling

Also, I can appreciate that my solution is quite clunky so would appreciate it if anyone has shorter/ more elegant way to code it so that I can expand it easily to multiple categories.

This is my (truncated) HTML:

```
<form>
    <select id = "courset" name = "coursetype">
        <option value = "PBL"> PBL</option>
        <option value = "Integrated">Integrated</option>
        <option value = "Traditional">Traditional</option>
        <option value = "Unsure">Not Sure</option>
    </select>
    <div id = "submit">
            <input type = "Submit">
    </div>
</form>
<table id = 'empTable'> 
    <thead>
        <tr> 
           <th scope = "col"> University</th>
           <th scope = "col"> Course Type</th>
           <th scope = "col"> GSCE Requirements</th>
           <th scope = "col"> A Level Requirements</th>
           <th scope = "col"> Admissions Test</th>
        </tr>
   
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr id= 'Uni1'>
                <td>Uni1</td>
                <td class = 'tabcourse'>Integrated</td>
                <td class = 'tabgcse'> 5 As </td>
                <td class = 'tabalevel'>AAA </td>       
                <td class = 'tabtest'>UCAT</td>
            </tr>
            <tr id= 'Uni2'>
                <td>Uni2</td>
                <td class = 'tabcourse'>Traditional</td>
                <td class = 'tabgcse'> 10 As </td>
                <td class = 'tabalevel'>CCC </td>       
                <td class = 'tabtest'>None</td>
            </tr>

            
        </tbody>
```

This is my JQuery and JS:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$('#submit').click(
    function submission(){
        var results = $("form").serializeArray();
        function admission () { 
                function showTableData() {
                    var myTab = document.getElementById('empTable');
                    // LOOP THROUGH EACH ROW OF THE TABLE AFTER HEADER.
                    for (i = 1; i < myTab.rows.length; i++) {
                        // GET THE CELLS COLLECTION OF THE CURRENT ROW.
                        var objCells = myTab.rows.item(i).cells;
                        // LOOP THROUGH EACH CELL OF THE CURENT ROW TO READ CELL VALUES.
                        for (var j = 0; j < objCells.length; j++) {
                            objCells.item(j).innerHTML
                            if (objCells.item(j).innerHTML === results[16].coursetype){
                                myTab.rows.item(i).style.borderColor = 'green';
                            }

                        }
                    }
                }
        }
    }
);


})
```

note that I used results[16] because imagine that coursetype is the 17th input item. I couldn't work out a better way to target the input.

*** UPDATE ***

So I amalgamated your solutions which worked pretty well. However, I've hit a block with this particular criteria. Note:  I needed a way for the JQuery to recognise that if someone selects value = 8, then they're also eligible for any unis with entry criteria <8.

Here's my HTML

```
<form>
    <select id = "Agrad" name = "A Level Grades">
        <option value = "8">A*A*A* </option>
        <option value = "7">A*A*A</option>
        <option value = "6">A*AA</option>
        <option value = "5">AAA</option>
        <option value = "4">AAB</option>
        <option value = "3">ABB</option>
        <option value = "2">BBB</option>
        <option value = "1">BBC</option>
        <option value = "0">BCC or lower</option>
     </select>
       <div id = "submit">
             <input type = "button" Value = "Submit">
       </div>
</form>
<table id = 'empTable'> 
        <thead>
            <tr> 
               <th scope = "col"> University</th>
               <th scope = "col"> Course Type</th>
               <th scope = "col"> GSCE Requirements</th>
               <th scope = "col"> A Level Requirements</th>
               <th scope = "col"> Admissions Test</th>
            </tr>
       
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr id= 'Uni1'  data-agrade = "5678">
                    <td>Uni1</td>
                    <td class = 'tabcourse'>Integrated</td>
                    <td class = 'tabgcse'> 5 As </td>
                    <td class = 'tabalevel'>AAA </td>       
                    <td class = 'tabtest'>UCAT</td>
                </tr>
                <tr id= 'Uni2'  data-agrade = "87654321">
                    <td>Uni2</td>
                    <td class = 'tabcourse'>Traditional</td>
                    <td class = 'tabgcse'> 10 As </td>
                    <td class = 'tabalevel'>CCC </td>       
                    <td class = 'tabtest'>None</td>
                </tr>
                <tr id= 'Uni3'  data-agrade = "8">
                    <td>Uni3</td>
                    <td class = 'tabcourse'>Integrated</td>
                    <td class = 'tabgcse'> 5 As </td>
                    <td class = 'tabalevel'>A*A*A* </td>       
                    <td class = 'tabtest'>UCAT</td>
                </tr>
                
            </tbody>
```

Here's my JQuery

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('input[type=button]').click(function() {
// A Grades 
        var selected_agrade = $("#Agrad").val();
        $("tr").each(function(tr_index, tr) {
            var needed_agrade = $("tr").attr("agrade");
            if(needed_agrade.includes(selected_agrade)) {
                $(tr).addClass('fit');
            } else {
                $(tr).removeClass('fit');
            }
        });

    });
});
```

Can you see any obvious reason why it's not working?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I've edited your html a little(maybe typo fixed, courset -> course) and rewritten your js code. If you use jQuery, you can easily find dom elements and manipulate it. Also if you use `each` of jQuery, it's easy to iterate through elements. Note that it's only working with this truncated html so you may need to handle selectors like `tr`.

```js
$('input[type=button]').click(function() {
    var selected_course = $("#course").val();

    $("tr").each(function(tr_index, tr) {
        var course = $(tr).find(".tabcourse").text();
        if(selected_course == course) {
            $(tr).addClass('green_background');
        } else {
            $(tr).removeClass('green_background');
        }
    });
});
```

```css
.green_background {
  background-color:green;
}
```

```html
<script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.min.js"
  integrity="sha256-9/aliU8dGd2tb6OSsuzixeV4y/faTqgFtohetphbbj0="crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<form>
  <select id = "course" name = "coursetype">
    <option value = "PBL"> PBL</option>
    <option value = "Integrated">Integrated</option>
    <option value = "Traditional">Traditional</option>
    <option value = "Unsure">Not Sure</option>
  </select>
  <div id = "submit">
    <input type = "button" Value="Submit" >
  </div>
</form>
<table id = 'empTable'> 
  <thead>
    <tr> 
      <th scope = "col"> University</th>
      <th scope = "col"> Course Type</th>
      <th scope = "col"> GSCE Requirements</th>
      <th scope = "col"> A Level Requirements</th>
      <th scope = "col"> Admissions Test</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr id= 'Uni1'>
      <td>Uni1</td>
      <td class = 'tabcourse'>Integrated</td>
      <td class = 'tabgcse'> 5 As </td>
      <td class = 'tabalevel'>AAA </td>       
      <td class = 'tabtest'>UCAT</td>
    </tr>
    <tr id= 'Uni2'>
      <td>Uni2</td>
      <td class = 'tabcourse'>Traditional</td>
      <td class = 'tabgcse'> 10 As </td>
      <td class = 'tabalevel'>CCC </td>       
      <td class = 'tabtest'>None</td>
    </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

There are two tried and true ways that many people might approach this problem. One way is to filter based on the value of a text node in a table cell `<td>someValue</td>` (the literal way of doing this), or filtering based on meta data embedded in the table cell opening tag using the `data-something="value"`) convention.

My inclination is to avoid dealing with text nodes in a situation like this due to various anomalies that can make dealing with them trickier than you might think. For instance, what if a table cell has an empty text node. What if the table cell `<td>` failed to materialize for some reason. I say go up one level and deal with the table row, `<tr>`.

First, you might think about embedding some useful attribute into each table row:

```
<tr data-type="1">

</tr>
<tr data-type="2">` 

</tr>
```

You will have to decide what you think is best. Using numbers for the attribute value is convenient, because then you can change the `value` attribute of the `<option>` tags in your `<select>` list to say something like:

```
<option value="1">PBL</option>
<option value="2">Integrated</option>
<option value="3">Traditional</option>
<option value="4">Not Sure</option>
```

However, for code clarity, this might be better.

```
<select id="courset" name="coursetype">
    <option value="All">All</option>
    <option value="PBL">PBL</option>
    <option value="Integrated">Integrated</option>
    <option value="Traditional">Traditional</option>
    <option value="Not_Sure">Not Sure</option>  <!-- A single word would be best -->
</select>

<tr data-type="Integrated">

</tr>
<tr data-type="Traditional">` 

</tr>
```

With each row containing essential meta information, your task becomes much easier than dealing with text nodes. Simply ...

var tbody = document.getElementById('idOfTbody'); 
var tableRows = tbody.getElementsByTagName('tr');

Now that you have all of the table rows in a variable, the game is a foot!

I might note that in situations like this, you end up needing to toggle on and off the rows depending on which option you pick from the select list. Be sure to have a way for all of the rows to show (hence, the all option or something similar).

Now, all you must do is loop through the table rows, and change the CSS to `display:none`. I would define a class in my CSS and use something like.

```
 someTableRow.className="remove";
```

Yes, you can do something like ...

```
 someTableRow.style.display="none";
```

... but, you really should take advantage of CSS classes in a case like this. However, if you bump into a complex situation in which there is already a class on the row, and you don't know how to deal with (**add and remove**) multiple classes in the .className string, just use the second way.

You pick the kind of loop you want. Here's a basic outline of what to do.
Note, there are various array functions (.filter(), .map(). blah, blah) that might enable you to do a .foreach() and what have you, but here is the most fundamental way to do this.

```
function filterTableRowsByAttribute (tableRows, rowAttribute, filterValue)
{
    var i,
        row;

    for (i=0; i < tableRows.length; i++) {
        row = tableRows[i];

        if (row.getAttribute(rowAttribute) !== filterValue) {
            removeElement(row);
        } else {
            showTableRow(row);
        }
    }
}

function removeElement(element)
{
    element.style.display="none";
}

function showTableRow (element)
{
    element.style.display="table-row";
}

var filterValue = "Integrated"; // Grab that value from the selection list.
var tbody = document.getElementById('tbodyId'); // Give your tbody an id 
var tableRows = tbody.getElementsByTagName('tr');
var targetAttribute = "data-type"

filterTableRowsByAttribute(tableRows, targetAttribute, filterValue);
```

### Conclusion

Making decisions about table rows by an attribute is simpler than dealing with text nodes, or fiddling with the innerHTML. Nested loops are not necessary. Break the problem down into steps. Don't let jQuery bamboozle you. :-) Filtering table rows is easier when the table row elements themselves have enough information to filter by.

The alternative would be to examine the text node in the appropriate table data cell, and then walk up the down to hide the table row.

Gather all table data cells to be examined.

```
var tableCells = document.getElementsByClassName("tabcourse");
```

Inspect and test the value of the text node inside of table data cell.

```
function filterTableRowsByCell(tableCells, filterValue)
{
    let i,
        cell,
        tableRows,
        row;

    tableRows = getTableRowsFromCells(tableCells) <!-- the extra step -->

    for (i = 0; i < tableCells.length; i++) {
        cell = tableCells[i];
        row = tableRows[i];

        if (cell.nodeValue !== filterValue) {
            removeElement(row);
        } else {
            showTableRow(row);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: So I tried amalgamating your solution with the one below but I seem to have a problem selecting the data attribute using JQUERY. I've also tried using the .data() method but doesn't seem to be working. I've put an update of my code above. Can you see any source of the problem? Thanks